# How to submit a signed transaction that has been XDR enveloped?

Tags: javascript-sdk, stellar-sdk

Hi I was working with Stellar on Javascript for offline signing and to keep the QR code after signing short I enveloped the transaction and converted it to XDR.

Using,

```
const signedTx = await transaction.toEnvelope().toXDR('base64');
```

Now how do I convert it back to the transaction object so that I can submit it?

I tried submitting this transaction but I keep on getting the error,

```
TypeError: transaction.toEnvelope is not a function
     at Server.<anonymous> (/opt/game/main/node_modules/stellar-sdk/lib/server.js:115:22)
     at step (/opt/game/main/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:136:27)
     at Object.next (/opt/game/main/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:117:57)
     at /opt/game/main/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:110:75
     at new Promise (<anonymous>)
     at Object.__awaiter (/opt/game/main/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:106:16)
     at Server.submitTransaction (/opt/game/node_modules/stellar-sdk/lib/server.js:111:24)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright even though I could not find any function to deserialize the `signedTx`, I did find a way.

If you create a new StellarSdk Object, call Transaction and input signedTx as a parameter into it, you get back the original transaction object.

Like so,

```
const transaction = new StelladSdk.Transaction(signedTx);
```

Comment: Isn't it `.submitTransaction(transaction)`?

Comment: I think at that point the issue was that the SDK expected the transaction to be transaction object, instead of being able to submit XDR